# Need help in this following NASM task

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I have written a program in NASM in Ubuntu11.04 which will take 2 input numbers and produce a sum. The program is the following:

```
    section .data
       msg1:    db "the numbers are:%d%d",0
       msg3:    db "REsult= %d",10,0
    section .bss
       a resd 1
       b resd 1
       sum resd 1
    section .text
      global main
      extern printf,scanf
    main:
;; push ebp
;; mov ebp,esp
;; sub esp,10

      push a
      push b
      push msg1
      call scanf
      add esp,12

      mov eax,DWORD[a]
      add eax,DWORD[b]
      mov DWORD[sum],eax

      push DWORD[sum]
      push msg3
      call printf
      add esp,8

;; mov esp,ebp
;; pop ebp
       ret
```

Will you pls help me to find out the mistake I have done here? I will also appreciate if you advice me any tutorial in NASM whether it is Vedio or text. I have gotten Art of Assembly Language or NASM Manual. But frst one is not based on NASM and 2nd one is difficult to get for a beginner like me.

Thanx

Comment: What's the error? What are the symptoms?

Comment: @EarlGray:I did the debugging. it shows that input is not stored in eax. So the result shows 0 everytime. And most dstrbing is that "The number are"  message was not shown at the time of input.

Comment: `msg1` needs to be terminated with a zero. You also need to exit cleanly. Either uncomment the `ret`, or call `exit`.

Comment: @FrankKotler:I am not sure whether u execute this program with your said modification or not. It does not work. I re edit my code above for your convenience

Comment: You're right, I didn't try it. You're right, it doesn't work. Apparently, `scanf` won't print the prompt (I'm not very familiar with C - I can show ya how to do it with system calls). I solved it by printing the prompt (with `printf`) first, then calling `scanf` with just `"%d%d", 0`. I should avoid trying to answer questions involving C!

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going:

```
global main
extern printf, scanf, exit

section .data 
scanf_fmt       db  "%d %d", 0
printf1_fmt     db  "The numbers entered are: %d and %d,", " The result = %d", 10, 0

main:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 8                          ; make room for 2 dwords

    lea     eax, [ebp - 4]                  ; get pointers to our locals
    lea     ecx, [ebp - 8]                  ;
    push    eax                             ; give pointers to scanf
    push    ecx                             ;
    push    scanf_fmt                       ;
    call    scanf                           ; read in 2 dwords
    add     esp, 12

    mov     eax, dword [ebp - 4]            ; add em together
    add     eax, dword [ebp - 8]            ;

    push    eax                             ; total
    push    dword [ebp - 4]                 ; second num
    push    dword [ebp - 8]                 ; first num
    push    printf1_fmt                     ; format string
    call    printf                          ; show it
    add     esp, 16                         

    add     esp, 8                          ; restore stack pointers
    mov     esp, ebp
    pop     ebp
    call    exit                            ; linking agaist the c libs, must use exit.
```

output:
[image]